# Sonar - reporting on most actively edited files?

Tags: sonarqube

I'd like to create a report in Sonar for the most actively edited files. I've looked around but can't find a plugin to do this. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

If relevant, my team uses AccuRev for SCM, and Sonar v2.14

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's currently no plugin that meets your need (at least none that I'm aware of).

I could have suggested you to develop your own plugin based on the metrics generated by the SCM Activity Plugin, but Accurev is not supported so you would have to start from scratch :-/

Comment: Thanks Fabrice. I'll hold on for another 24 hours to see if anyone else has any crazy workaround suggestions. Otherwise will accept your answer